# Python set - Should update have been named as union_update?

Tags: python-3.x

**Update example:**

```
x = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
y = {"google", "microsoft", "apple"}

x.update(y) 

print(x)
```

{'microsoft', 'cherry', 'banana', 'google', 'apple'}

**Union example:**

```
x = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
y = {"google", "microsoft", "apple"}

z = x.union(y) 

print(z)
```

{'google', 'cherry', 'apple', 'microsoft', 'banana'}

The difference between update and union methods is whether or not the inplace update happens. This is similar to for example - intersection vs intersection_update.

Should update have been named as union_update?

Comment: Maybe? Why one name was chosen over another isn't really a question that can be answered objectively. My guess is that `intersection_update` was added some time after `update`; until then, there was no need to call out what *kind* of update `update` performed, as it was the *only* kind of update. Once there was a distinction to be made, it wasn't deemed necessary to provide an alias to `update` that described in more accurately.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its offtopic

Comment: Contradicting my comment above, I *did* find in the [documentation of the old `set` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) a reference to such an alias: "Also note, the module also includes a union_update() method which is an alias for update(). The method is included for backwards compatibility. Programmers should prefer the update() method because it is supported by the built-in set() and frozenset() types."

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to union() method, with difference is that where union() method create and return a new set, containing all the elements ( distinct ) present in all the iterables, update() method updates the set on which this method is called with all the distinct elements present in all the iterables.

Visit this site for more understanding,
https://codedestine.com/python-set-union-example/

Answer (score -1):

No, Both Union and Update are different , it has not been renamed.
What are you trying to achieve?